# If a question has an accepted answer, do you remove the edited OP showing the solution?

Tags: discussion

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226560/instantiating-an-inherited-class-from-a-string) and had the answer marked as the accepted answer. The OP then edited his question so that it included the solution.

Should I edit and remove the solution from the OP, as the question has an accepted answer that shows the same thing? If not, would you move the solution shown by the OP to the bottom of his question, so that the actual question stays at the top of the post?

Comment: Yes, roll back the question. The answer belongs only in the answers. (Be sure to comment and let the OP know that for the future.)

Comment: @Kendra Thanks, I'll roll it back.